# Google Calendar API Failed to create new key

Tags: google-api

I get the following error when I try to create a OAuth New Client ID for a Service Account.

```
An internal error occurred:  
   Error (projectId=xxxxx) INTERNAL:  
   Failed to create new key for client: xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com,  
   reason: Internal robots may not specify public certs
```

Comment: Provide details of your implementation

Comment: Sure. I am trying to setup a new project

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My first time doing this… I am trying to setup a new project in order to update my calendars using the API via REST. Following the links in the console.developers.google.com, I get to step 4 of 'Get familiar with Google Developers Console'. Under OAuth, I get the error message when I try to create a Service Account Client ID. I think I have followed the steps correctly so far.